# Не могу сохранить указатель на функцию c++ qt

Tags: c++, qt

у меня есть функция, которую надо сохранить в указателе. Работаю в QT, во время компиляции генерирует ошибку. Может кто помочь?
Код следующий:

```
pclCloudFilter::pclCloudFilter(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    void (*t_func)();
    t_func = &pclCloudFilter::custt;
}

void pclCloudFilter::custt()
{
    qDebug() << "class pclCloudFilter get clouds";
}
```

[image: Ошибка которая сгенерирована]

Comment: Ясно же сказано - различные типы возврата. bool и void.

Comment: Извините, эскпериментировал и забыл исправить, можете сейчас посмотреть

Comment: там просто функция и функция-член класса. А они между собой не совместимы.

Comment: Не подскажите, как можно исправить?

Comment: где то так `void (pclCloudFilter::*t_func)();`

Answer (score 5):

Если `void pclCloudFilter::custt()` не объявлена как `static`, то указатель на неё должен быть типа указатель на член-функцию, как уже ответил @KoVadim в комментарии:

```
void (pclCloudFilter::*t_func)();
```

Обычный указатель на функцию не годится, т.к. кроме явных параметров функции, в неё ещё неявно передаётся текущий экземпляр класса `this`. (`void (*t_func)(pclCloudFilter*);` тоже не подойдёт, `this` передаётся хитрее, чем просто параметр)

Указатель на член-функцию используется с операторами `.*` и `->*`, вызов будет выглядеть так:

```
void (pclCloudFilter::*t_func)();
...
pclCloudFilter* inst = ...;
...
(inst->*t_func)();
```

Ужасная конструкция. Обычно с таким не имеют дело напрямую.

Используют:

- `std::mem_fn` для превращения указателя на член-функцию в функтор
- `std::bind`, `std::bind_front`, `boost::bind` тоже для превращения указателя на член-функцию в функтор, плюс для захвата `this` и/или другого контекста
- лямбды - для коротких обёрток вызова члена-функции (при этом указатель на член-функцию вообще не нужен)
- Обобщённый объект функции `std::function` или `boost::function` для хранения любого функтора со стиранием типа
- сигналы `Boost.Signals2`, Qt slot/signals для реализации паттерна "обозреватель"

Comment: `t_func->*inst` ???? maybe `inst->*t_func`?